# Error Installing Python Packages that depend on scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, scipy, package

There seems to be some issue with the scipy package that is installed in my laptop (scipy 1.10.0) where I am not able to install any package that is dependent on it nor am I able to upgrade scipy itself. Any help regarding this problem is appreciated. Attaching the error message below.

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.10.0.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [49 lines of output]
      + meson setup --prefix=C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iv7o01rz\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iv7o01rz\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b\.mesonpy-yp0zww37\build --native-file=C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iv7o01rz\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.0.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iv7o01rz\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b
      Build dir: C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iv7o01rz\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b\.mesonpy-yp0zww37\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.10.0
      WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

      ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iv7o01rz\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b\.mesonpy-yp0zww37\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-767_1ei5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 1060, in build_wheel
          with _project(config_settings) as project:
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-767_1ei5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 975, in _project
          with Project.with_temp_working_dir(
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-767_1ei5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 750, in with_temp_working_dir
          yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir, meson_args)
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-767_1ei5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 632, in __init__
          self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-767_1ei5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 680, in _configure
          self._meson('setup', *setup_args)
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-767_1ei5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 657, in _meson
          return self._proc('meson', *args)
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-767_1ei5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 652, in _proc
          subprocess.check_call(list(args), env=self._env)
        File "C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--prefix=C:\\Users\\prajw\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32', 'C:\\Users\\prajw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iv7o01rz\\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b', 'C:\\Users\\prajw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iv7o01rz\\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b\\.mesonpy-yp0zww37\\build', '--native-file=C:\\Users\\prajw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iv7o01rz\\scipy_d283c951218744039db0af58900fff2b\\.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

Since none of the package installs worked, I thought it might be a problem with the version so I tried upgrading it which seemed to result in the same issue.

Comment: what's the python version that you're using?

Comment: You are running 32bit version of Python3.8. Scipy provides a binary wheel only for 64bit version.  In order to fix this issues; install visual studio - details here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers **OR** switch to 64bit version of python if possible (uninstall current one and install another)